# How to make two way communication using ibeacons in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, ibeacon

I want to send data from one iPhone device to another iPhone device, in that one device work as transmitter and other work as receiver. Receiver can also send data to transmitter(server).

So is there any way using code to do this ?

Comment: http://www.devfright.com/ibeacons-tutorial-ios-7-clbeaconregion-clbeacon/ - maybe you can be a transmitter, putting your data comm into the NSDictionary and change dictionaries per your needs?

Comment: this way we can transmit data but how to get receiver's response to transmitter ?

Answer (score 5):

iBeacon is a **transmit-only proximity technology**, that's why it's found in the [Core Location framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html). It is not designed, nor does it support, bi-directional communication. An iBeacon advertises its presence and that is all.

If you want to perform data transfer over Bluetooth, have a look at the [Core Bluetooth framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html) and its samples, such as the [CoreBluetooth Temperature Sensor sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TemperatureSensor/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012194).